# Display tag-struts2 pagination issue when displaying large number of records

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, pagination, displaytag

I am working on struts 2 project with Display tag and I need to display upto 50K records from Database. Everything working fine but display tag going to call action/controller again when I am clicking on pagination numbers. This is not expected behavior since I am getting results using some session attributes and removing them after getting my Result Bean.

Here patientRecordsList is of type patientBean. I am getting this from DB with the help of session attributes and I am removing them after getting this list. Since display tag is calling action again on pagination so I am getting null pointer exception when using pagination. Here is my jsp code. Please help me in resolving this

```
<s:if test='%{#request.patientRecordsList != null}'>

<div class="displayTableFrame" style="margin-top: 20px; padding-top: 30px;">
 <display:table id="PatientTable" class="table table-bordered" name="patientRecordsList" pagesize="5" cellpadding="5px;" 
cellspacing="5px;" style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:20px;" requestURI="">
testing dtag
<display:column property="firstName" title="firstName"/>
<display:column property="lastName" title="lastName"/>
<display:column property="cardholderID" title="cardholderID"/>
<display:column property="contractID" title="contractID"/>
<display:column property="planID" title="planID"/>
<display:column property="claimNumber" title="claimNumber"/>
<display:column property="requestor" title="requestor"/>
<display:column property="providerType" title="providerType"/>
<display:column property="requestDate" title="requestDate"/>
<display:column property="diagnosis" title="diagnosis"/>

</display:table>
</div>
</s:if>
```

Comment: When you say `session`, do you mean the actual HTTP session or are you actually implying request attributes that you got from the GET/POST operation?

Comment: What do you mean "with the help of session attributes"? I mean, if you remove them... they won't be there any more.